# Loop through JSON and add new key-value data

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I have a big json data set like this:

```
{
   "10001": {
       "coords": [
           "40.753793,-74.007026/40.750272,-74.00828",
           "40.751445,-74.00143/40.752055,-74.000975",
           "40.751439,-73.99768/40.752723,-73.99679"
       ],
       "meta": {
           "city": "New York",
           "state": "NY",
           "latCenter": 40.71,
           "lngCenter": -73.99
       }
   },
   "10002": {
       "coords": [
           "40.714069,-73.997504/40.709181,-73.996222/40.709485,-73.994022"
       ],
       "meta": {
           "city": "New York",
           "state": "NY",
           "latCenter": 40.71,
           "lngCenter": -73.99
       }
   },
   and so on....
}
```

I need to add a new `"key" : "value"` data in the `"meta"` category. I tried to use `JSON.parse` to convert it to JavaScript object, but it doesn't work. It says the JSON format is not correct. And even after conversion, how to actually access to meta section via a loop and add the new values there, keeping the old format and data?

Comment: Please post your current code

Comment: basically you need some key, like `10001`. and use it as accessor for the object.

Comment: *"It says the JSON format is not correct."* What does it **actually** say? What you've shown above, aside from the "and so on...." part, is valid JSON.

Comment: the json is valid...from everything i tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = {
   "10001": {
       "coords": [
           "40.753793,-74.007026/40.750272,-74.00828",
           "40.751445,-74.00143/40.752055,-74.000975",
           "40.751439,-73.99768/40.752723,-73.99679"
       ],
       "meta": {
           "city": "New York",
           "state": "NY",
           "latCenter": 40.71,
           "lngCenter": -73.99
       }
   },
   "10002": {
       "coords": [
           "40.714069,-73.997504/40.709181,-73.996222/40.709485,-73.994022"
       ],
       "meta": {
           "city": "New York",
           "state": "NY",
           "latCenter": 40.71,
           "lngCenter": -73.99
       }
   }
};

// inject key "hello" with value "world"
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => Object.assign(data[key].meta, { "hello": "world" }));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Object.keys(object)` method:

```js
var obj={
   "10001": {
       "coords": [
           "40.753793,-74.007026/40.750272,-74.00828",
           "40.751445,-74.00143/40.752055,-74.000975",
           "40.751439,-73.99768/40.752723,-73.99679"
       ],
       "meta": {
           "city": "New York",
           "state": "NY",
           "latCenter": 40.71,
           "lngCenter": -73.99
       }
   },
   "10002": {
       "coords": [
           "40.714069,-73.997504/40.709181,-73.996222/40.709485,-73.994022"
       ],
       "meta": {
           "city": "New York",
           "state": "NY",
           "latCenter": 40.71,
           "lngCenter": -73.99
       }
   }
}

var keys=Object.keys(obj);
for(i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
  obj[keys[i]]["meta"]["key"]=0;
}
console.log(obj);
```